# What is the best way to dynamically lay out a lot of little items in a Windows Forms Panel?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `Panel` which is going to hold a lot of small `UserControl` objects which are basically just wrappers for a `PictureBox` with a `Label`. I would like to lay them out intelligently in such a way that when the window is resized, they are relocated similar to how `FlowLayout` in Java works.

I can hack out a way to relocate them on a resize event, but I would like to know if there is something built-in which would help before I attempt this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into the [FlowLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.aspx) control it should handle what you're after.

Edit: Alternatively, though less desirable in my mind, you can use Docking to help.